# ALGORITHM to simulate any Deterministic Pushdown Automata (DPDA)

Tags: simulate, any, deterministic, pushdown-automaton

how to write a program that can model any Deterministic Pushdown Automata (DPDA)
the user should enter number of states, transition functions, input symbols
the program should model the pda requested for
and test for the acceptance or rejection of random strings entered by the user

this is what i have done so far in c++
-i have collected the number of states, input symbols, and the input symbols
-i am on the transition function but cant seem to go further because i just cannot conceptualize modelling the DPDA

Comment: Your question is very specific but it might help to show a little source code.

Comment: thanks...got a great inspiration from GOD yday...on it...sure 2 keep u  posted

Comment: aii...now theres something...how can i empty a stack...pls i need a swift response

Comment: Assign another empty stack to it ...

Comment: hmmn...thanks...do i need to initialize the empty stack and how...i am kind of new with stacks

Comment: Something like pStack = std::stack<SomeType>();

Comment: what can make a an else block to run after its if block has ran

Comment: thanks but do u need to initialize the empty stack...i mean how do u initialize a stack to empty...m kind of new with stack

Comment: That's what I showed in the previous comment. Maybe you need to ask a new question for specific points.